# How to compare double in delphi?

Tags: delphi, types

We are facing issue with data type double comparison:

```
if(p > pmax) then
begin
  Showmessage('');
end
```

If both values are 100 (p=100 and pmax = 100), then also it is going inside if clause.

Comment: @Simon: There's a German site http://if-schleife.de/. [Google Translate makes](http://translate.google.de/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fif-schleife.de%2F) `There are no if-loops, but only if statements!` of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several problems with comparing Doubles. One problem is that what you see is not exactly what you get due to rounding. You can have 99.999999996423 and 100.00000000001632, which are both rounded to 100, but they are not equal.

The solution is to use a margin so that, if the difference of the two Doubles lies within the margin, you accept them as equal.

You can create an IsEqual function using the margin as an optional parameter:

```
function IsEqual(const ANumber1, ANumber2: Double; const AMargin: Double = cMargin): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Abs(ANumber1-ANumber2) <= AMargin;
end;
```

Comment: Note the your correct solution is already available in Math.pas as 'SameValue'.

Answer (score 69):

The Math.pas unit includes functions such as `SameValue()`, `IsZero()`, `CompareValue()` which handle floating type comparisons and equality.

```
const
  EPSILON = 0.0000001;
begin    
  if CompareValue(p, pMax, EPSILON) = GreaterThanValue then
    ShowMessage('p greater than pMax');
```

The constant `GreaterThanValue` is defined in Types.pas

**If you're comparing very large values** you shouldn't use a constant for epsilon, instead your epsilon value should be calculated based on the values you're comparing.

```
var
  epsilon: double;
begin    
  epsilon := Max(Min(Abs(p), Abs(pMax)) * 0.000001, 0.000001);
  if CompareValue(p, pMax, epsilon) = GreaterThanValue then
    ShowMessage('p greater than pMax');
```

Note that if you use `CompareValue(a, b, 0)` or in XE2 and later `CompareValue(a, b)`, Delphi will automatically fill in a good epsilon for you.

**From the Delphi `Math` unit:**

```
function SameValue(const A, B: Extended; Epsilon: Extended): Boolean;
begin
  if Epsilon = 0 then
    Epsilon := Max(Min(Abs(A), Abs(B)) * ExtendedResolution, ExtendedResolution);
  if A > B then
    Result := (A - B) <= Epsilon
  else
    Result := (B - A) <= Epsilon;
end;
```

**As of Delphi XE2** there are now overloads for all these functions that do not require an epsilon parameter and instead calculate one for you (similar to passing a 0 value for epsilon). For code clarity I would recommend calling these simpler functions and let Delphi handle the epsilon.

The only reason not to use the overloads without epsilon parameters would be when performance is crucial and you want to avoid the overhead of having the epsilon repeatedly calculated.

Comment: Thanks a lot..looks it is working..yesterday i have tried this but am not aware of Types.pas..

Comment: -100 for using a fixed value of epsilon, I've edited the answer instead to fix the issue.

Comment: I would believe that, if someone is using a fixed Epsilon and that causes them problems, their problem isn't Epsilon but the fact that Double/Extended isn't precise enough for their needs anymore. Personally, I'll keep using fixed value for Epsilon in my work. Once the value of the Extended variables I use reach a point where they can be more than $0.005 off, Epsilon will be the last of my concerns.

Comment: @Johan: -100 if I could for editing that changed content. If you disagree with the answer, post your own and downvote the one you feel is wrong. If you have grammar or formatting changes, edit. If you disagree with the answer, vote it down. Modifying it to a different meaning isn't how editing should be done.

Comment: @Ken, it had a bug in it, the code would break when using large values. The whole point of editing is to fix errors, be they spelling, content or whatnot (see the help when you edit an answer)

Comment: @LachlanG I am using CompareValue(a, b, 0)..will it be a impact on comparison?? i want compare upto .0000 what epsilion i can give??

Comment: If you give 0 for epsilon, Delphi will auto-calculate a reasonable epsilon, see the code snippet for the Math unit in the answer above.

Comment: @Ken Bourassa, you should never ever choose a fixed value for epsilon. Even with extended, it will outscope sooner than you think.

Comment: Never is a bit too strong I feel. If you know your data will always be within a fixed range why add the overhead of recalculating the epsilon with every calculation. Calculate an appropriate epsilon once then make that your epsilon constant.