# Delphi wrong double precision calculation

Tags: delphi, floating-point

I am having a problem calculating a simple arithmetic equation using double precision variables.

I have a component that has a property Value which is of double precision, and I am setting this property to 100.

Then I am doing a simple subtraction to check if this value is really 100:

```
var
check: double;
begin
  check:= 100 - MyComponent.Value
  showmessage(floattostr(check));
end;
```

The problem is that I don't get zero, I get -1.4210854715202E-14, which is a problem because I the program checks if this result is exactly zero

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic http://http://floating-point-gui.de/  And did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106119/how-to-compare-double-in-delphi and e.g. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Math.IsZero

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you claim otherwise, the value returned by `MyComponent.Value` is clearly not exactly equal to `100`. If it was, then `100 - MyComponent.Value` would be exactly equal to `0`. We can say that because `100` is exactly representable in binary floating point.

It's easy enough to see that `100.0 - 100.0 = 0.0`.

```
var
  x, y: Double;
....
x := 100.0;
y := 100.0;
Assert(x-y=0.0);
```

You will find, in your scenario, that

```
MyComponent.Value = 100.0
```

evaluates as `False`.

In general, it can always be a dangerous thing to try to compare floating point values exactly. Particularly if the values are the result of arithmetic operations, then the inherent imprecision of floating point operations will mean that exact comparison will often not give the results that you expect.

I hypothesise that `MyComponent.Value` actually performs arithmetic rather than, as you claim, returning `100.0`.

Sometimes the best way to check for equality with floating point values is to check for approximate equality. For example, `abs(x-y)<tol` where `tol` is some small number. The difficulty with that is that it can be hard to come up with a robust choice of  `tol`.

Exactly how you should implement this test is hard to say without knowing more detail.

Comment: The value from MyComponent.Value is for sure 100. I also printed this value using: showmessage(FormatFloat('#.#######E-##', MyComponent.Value). And I got 1E2. But when I do the subtraction, I got something else... But your tolerance idea is a good one, I also though about that, but I would like to understand why this happens and if there is a smarter way of fixing this problem, but considering the uncertainty of floating point operation, I guess I should use this tolerance idea

Comment: No. 100% for sure, the value is not 100. If it was, MyComponent.Value=100 would evaluate to True. And it won't. When you used FormatFloat you rounded to a small number of significant figures.

Comment: If you still don't believe me, try this: `ShowMessage(FormatFloat('#.#######E-##', 99.999999999))`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are right that the value returned by MyComponent.Value is not 100.0, but your statement in the last comment only provides half the explanation why a non-100.0 value prints as 100.0. After all, the double-precision 99.9999999999999999 prints as 100.0 because it **is** 100.0. To be conclusive, your statement should **also** print 99.999999999 with more decimal digits in order to show that it is actually not 100.0.

Answer (score 4):

When using floating point numbers, you should never perform exact compares; always use a small `Epsilon` value as explained in [The Floating-Point Guide - What Every Programmer Should Know](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

> Note: I deliberately state this in an absolute sense. Of course there
>   are exceptions, but in practice these are usually exceptional. Of
>   course you might be in the situation that your problem domain is
>   exceptional, and warrants exact compares. In the vast majority of code
>   that I have maintained, this is not the case.

The `Math` unit (it has been with Delphi for a long long time) contains the below functions that handle `Epsilon` values for you.

When you pass an `Epsilon` of zero (i.e. `0.0`) or no value at all to the functions below, they will estimate an reasonable value using these constants.

Note:

> The appropriate value of `Epsilon` you want to use depends on the
>   calculations you use: sometimes inaccuracies can accumulate to much
>   larger values than these constants.

```
const
  FuzzFactor = 1000;
  SingleResolution   = 1E-7 * FuzzFactor;
  DoubleResolution   = 1E-15 * FuzzFactor;
{$IFDEF EXTENDEDIS10BYTES}
  ExtendedResolution = 1E-19 * FuzzFactor;
{$ELSE  EXTENDEDIS10BYTES}
  ExtendedResolution = DoubleResolution;
{$ENDIF EXTENDEDIS10BYTES}
```

The functions:

```
function CompareValue(const A, B: Extended; Epsilon: Extended = 0): TValueRelationship; overload;
function CompareValue(const A, B: Double; Epsilon: Double = 0): TValueRelationship; overload;
function CompareValue(const A, B: Single; Epsilon: Single = 0): TValueRelationship; overload;

function SameValue(const A, B: Extended; Epsilon: Extended = 0): Boolean; overload;
function SameValue(const A, B: Double; Epsilon: Double = 0): Boolean; overload;
function SameValue(const A, B: Single; Epsilon: Single = 0): Boolean; overload;

function IsZero(const A: Extended; Epsilon: Extended = 0): Boolean; overload;
function IsZero(const A: Double; Epsilon: Double = 0): Boolean; overload;
function IsZero(const A: Single; Epsilon: Single = 0): Boolean; overload;
```

Comment: There are plenty of times when it is apt to compare floating point values exactly. And times when it is a bad idea. It is not as clear cut as you state.

Comment: In my scenario I compare user entered data with other user entered data. So I might have a property setter and I'd write `if NewValue<>OldValue`. Or I might have memoisation or caching optimisation for which exact comparison of the input parameters would be apt.

Comment: `might` is a bit vague. Do you have more concrete criteria when you choose between exact and epsilon based comparison?

Comment: I use exact comparison in the cases where exact is the right choice. I don't think you are going to get a concrete set of rules. Each case is judged on its own merits.

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you never check for zero by simple subtraction when one of the numbers is a float. Instead, use the IsZero function with whatever precision you want (e.g., 0.00001) for the Epsilon parameter.

```
procedure CheckFor100(MyPrecision);
begin
  if IsZero(100 - MyComponent.Value, MyPrecision) then
    ShowMessage('MyComponent value was 100')
  else
    ShowMessage('MyComponent value was not 100');
end;
```

Alternatively, you may wish to consider the SameValue function. I think both IsZero and SameValue are in the Math unit.